# Problema con Full screen VLCJ

Tags: java, video, vlcj

Tengo un programa que en una de las ventanas se muestra un video y no consigo hacer que el boton de full screen (jButton3) funcione.

```
package estanquet;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultFullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.x.XFullScreenStrategy;



public class Video extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent player;
private File file;
EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
static{
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "src/DLL/");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

}
private boolean band = true;


public Video() {

    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);//centrar en pantalla
    player = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    //se añade reproductor 
    jPanel14.add(player);       
    player.setSize(jPanel14.getSize());
    player.setVisible(true);
    jButton6.setVisible(false);

}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel13 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel15 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel16 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel17 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel18 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel14 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));
    setUndecorated(true);

    jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));
    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel13.setOpaque(false);
    jPanel13.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    jPanel15.setOpaque(false);
    jPanel15.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 150));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel15Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel15);
    jPanel15.setLayout(jPanel15Layout);
    jPanel15Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel15Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 1920, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel15Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel15Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel13.add(jPanel15, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    jPanel16.setOpaque(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel16Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel16);
    jPanel16.setLayout(jPanel16Layout);
    jPanel16Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel16Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 1920, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel16Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel16Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel13.add(jPanel16, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    jPanel17.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(277, 860));
    jPanel17.setOpaque(false);
    jPanel17.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(277, 860));

    jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Interfaz/volver.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);
    jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jButton1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jButton1.setIconTextGap(0);
    jButton1.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Interfaz/ampliar.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setBorderPainted(false);
    jButton3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jButton3.setDefaultCapable(false);
    jButton3.setFocusPainted(false);
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel17Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel17);
    jPanel17.setLayout(jPanel17Layout);
    jPanel17Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel17Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel17Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel17Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel17Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGroup(jPanel17Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)))
            .addContainerGap(106, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel17Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel17Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel17Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(54, 54, 54)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addContainerGap(515, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel13.add(jPanel17, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    jPanel18.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(277, 860));
    jPanel18.setOpaque(false);
    jPanel18.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(277, 860));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel18Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel18);
    jPanel18.setLayout(jPanel18Layout);
    jPanel18Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel18Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 277, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel18Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel18Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 830, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel13.add(jPanel18, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    jPanel14.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jPanel14.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));

    jButton2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Interfaz/play_f.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setBorder(null);
    jButton2.setBorderPainted(false);
    jButton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jButton2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    jButton2.setDefaultCapable(false);
    jButton2.setFocusPainted(false);
    jButton2.setIconTextGap(0);
    jButton2.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Interfaz/PLAY_1.png"))); // NOI18N
    jButton6.setBorderPainted(false);
    jButton6.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jButton6.setDefaultCapable(false);
    jButton6.setFocusPainted(false);
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel14Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel14);
    jPanel14.setLayout(jPanel14Layout);
    jPanel14Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel14Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel14Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel14Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel14Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGroup(jPanel14Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 647, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGap(655, 655, 655))
    );
    jPanel14Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel14Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel14Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(308, 308, 308)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 354, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton6))
    );

    jPanel13.add(jPanel14, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jPanel1.add(jPanel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1920, 1080));

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Interfaz/menu-interfaz-fondo(1).jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, -1, -1));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    player.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("src/Video/Video Proyecto.mp4");
    jButton2.setVisible(false);
    jButton6.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Index a = new Index();
    a.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
    player.getMediaPlayer().setPause( player.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()?true:false );
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                                        

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    player.getMediaPlayer().setPause( player.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()?true:false );
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Video.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Video.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Video.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Video.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Video().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel13;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel14;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel15;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel16;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel17;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel18;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igual me equivoco, pero visto un poco así por encima debido a las horas que son yo aquí no veo que haga nada.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}
```

Osea tu puedes declarar el propio action en los mismos parametros del addActionListener pero si luego lo mandas a ese metodo y no hay absolutamente nada, es normal que no funcione no se digo yo jajajaja, solo soy un usuario más intentando compartir conocimientos espero que lo arregles pronto.
Saludos internauta. :)

Comment: Se me olvido poner que ya habia intentado setbounds y setsize con player y no funcionaba.. aun asi esta en blanco esa parte porque borre aquello que no funcionaba.

Comment: Has probado con Video.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
Video.setUndecorated(true);
Video.setVisible(true);???